# Setting up the ChromeDriver for selenide using experimental features (download.default_directory) in conjunction with using selenide browser defaults

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenide

I'm looking for the best way to set up the chromium browser to allow downloads while accepting the default selenide settings.

We had the ChromeDriver working based solely on the selenium system properties (headless, windowSize, etc.)

I now have file downloads working, but it's via hard coding properties into the chrome driver that are also defined in the system configuration file.

So I'm wondering how do I allow the download of files into a specified folder (dynamically when creating the ChromeDriver) while still using the other default settings in the selenide Configuration.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the best way to merge System defined properties for selenide with the experimental file download properties needed to download files in Chrome?  Is there a way to add experimental properties to the ChromeDriver while letting it read in the default properties?
2. Relatedly, is there a way of using the WebDriverProvider to read in Selenium options, which are being set correctly in the configuration, but are not present in the DesiredCapabilites being passed in.
3. Finally (additional context for my end goal) we're trying to save files based on the names of the testng suite they are being run from.  I know how to get the suite name when creating the chromedriver, but I'm not sure the best way to make it available to the webdriverprovider, if that is the final solution.

Sample 1: Working download function:

```
private void saveDownloadsIntoDesiredDirectory(String downloadFolderName) {

        if (Configuration.browser.equals("chrome")) {
            HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);

            //THIS must be the canonicalPath,otherwise it won't work on Windows.
            try {
                chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", new File(downloadFolderName).getCanonicalPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
            chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);

            //THIS took forever to find.
            chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.disable_download_protection",true);
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.addArguments("--headless");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--window-size=1280,1024");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.getTitle();
            WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
        }
    }
```

I thought the proper way to fix it might be a WebDriverProvider .. but I'm not seeing the benefits of it. This is where it currently stands.  The duplication of configuration parameters below can't be the best way to do this.

```
package core;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverProvider;

public class SaveFileWebDriverProviderShared implements WebDriverProvider {

    @Override
    public WebDriver createDriver(DesiredCapabilities capabilities) {

            System.out.println("CLE headless" + Configuration.headless);
            System.out.println(Configuration.browserSize);
            DesiredCapabilities dc2 = Configuration.browserCapabilities;
            Set<String> test= dc2.getCapabilityNames();

            HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);

            //THIS must be the canonicalPath,otherwise it won't work on Windows.
//            try {
//                chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", new File("/tmp/downloadTest",afs.getActiveSuite()) );
            File downloadFolder = new File("/tmp/downloadTest/CLETEst");
            downloadFolder.mkdir();

          //THIS must be the canonicalPath,otherwise it won't work on Windows.
            try {
                chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFolder.getCanonicalPath() );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }    

            chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
            chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", true);

            //THIS took forever to find.
            chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.disable_download_protection",true);

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

            if(Configuration.headless) {
                options.addArguments("--headless");
            }
            if(Configuration.browserSize != null) {
                options.addArguments("--window-size="+Configuration.browserSize.replace('x', ','));
            }
            options.merge(capabilities);

            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            return driver;
    }

}
```

Technical detail:

Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.11 (eaaae9de6b8999773fa33f92ce1e1bbe294437cf-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#86})

Comment: Ok, the reason I wasn't getting the headless and window size options in the webdriverprovider is that I needed to use 
            options.merge(capabilities.chrome());  
Instead of 
            options.merge(capabilities);

Comment: I'm also setting the folder via a ThreadLocal static variable.  Will need to test it in parallel later, but it should work for now.